# Can anyone let me know how to call a postgres db function & procedure in c++ using with pqxx library?

Tags: c++, postgresql

I'm working with C++ database application we are looking to migrate oracle to Postgre so need help to call Postgre db function & procedure . I'm using pqxx library to connect & transaction data with database .using pqxx library I'm able to connect and insert and update data in to database but un able to call db function and procedure in my C++ code . Can anyone please help me on this ?

I have a sample function ->  `ec_special_item$bhutan_getitem`

code started below ->

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."ec_special_item$bhutan_getitem"(
INOUT ai_presentingbank text,
ai_bankroutingnum integer,
OUT ao_numerrorid integer,
OUT ao_strerrordesc text,
OUT ao_item_state text)
    RETURNS record
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  
BEGIN
        ai_presentingbank:='12345678';
        INSERT INTO public.Tyre(item_type_code, description)VALUES (ai_bankroutingnum, 'outward');
        
        SELECT
            UPPER(description) AS Tyre into ao_item_state
            FROM public.Tyre
            WHERE LOWER(description)  = 'inward'
        ;
    ao_numerrorid := 50;
    ao_strerrordesc := 'PASS';
     RETURN ;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN others THEN
            
            ao_numerrorid := 0;
            ao_strerrordesc := 'FAIL';
        
            RETURN ;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: How would you call a "db function and procedure" in the normal Postgres shell? Isn't that the same as a regular query?

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I'm using pqxx library to call function in my c++ code like ....

Comment: String sql = ("SELECT PUBLIC.COMPANY()");     pqxx::result r = W.exec(sql);

Comment: the above one is working and i'm able to call db function of postgres using pqxx library

Comment: But I want to call db function with input and out put parameters how can I ?

Comment: Please edit your question with an example of a function you want to call, inputs and outputs.

Comment: That is the definition. How would you call it normally from the postgres commandline?

Comment: It could be operating system specific, and compiler specific. With a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, compile the C++ code with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: I'm using Visual studio 2019 version with C++ code and I'm able to insert data in to data base also but my query is how can I call these function in my C++ code and how can I get out values ?

Answer (score 2):

The PostgreSQL [documentation on the `CALL` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-call.html) states:

> If the procedure has any output parameters, then a result row will be returned, containing the values of those parameters.

So you should treat the `CALL` expression like a `SELECT` and process the single resulting row.

If you adapt the [quick example](http://www.pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/#quick-example), it should look something like:

```
pqxx::work txn{c};

pqxx::result r{txn.exec("CALL ec_special_item$bhutan_getitem('some_bank', 12345)"};
for (auto row: r)
    std::cout
    << "\nai_presentingbank: " << row["ai_presentingbank"].c_str()
    << "\nao_numerrorid: " << row["ao_numerrorid"].as<int>()
    << "\nao_strerrordesc: " << row["ao_strerrordesc"].c_str()
    << "\nao_item_state: " << row["ao_item_state"].c_str()
    << std::endl;
}

txn.commit();
```

Comment: Hi , I have tried as per the above suggestion but getting error while running the program can you please check it once

Comment: Opened database successfully: postgres
ERROR:  column "some_bank" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT public.ec_special_item$bhutan_getitem("some_bank", 12...
                                                     ^


C:\Postgresql\Project\Subramanyam\x64\Release\Subramanyam.exe (process 10692) exited with code 1.
Press any key to close this window . . .

Comment: I'm getting above ERROR : column "some_bank" does not exist....    how can I resolve this ?

Comment: That's what you get when you post untested answers... Postgres strings are single quoted, not double quoted. Edited.